# Spring boot , Eureka server , IBM WAS : logback gives NoClassDefFoundError ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a problem when starting a spring boot application (Eureka server )( tried :1.4.0 , 1.3.7 , 1.3.6 ) on IBM Websphere Application server ( 8.5.5.9) with jdk 8 , it throws the following exception :

```
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1178)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1383)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:972)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:777)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1380)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2191)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:653)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5486)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5612)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:667)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:611)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1270)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:483 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:620)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:246)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.console.appdeployment.ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.execute(ApplicationDeploymentCollectionAction.java:608)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:484 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistance(WSCUrlFilter.java:964)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:511)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:332)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:940)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1820)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:485 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:486 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:486 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:486 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:486 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   ... 97 more
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:177)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   ... 99 more
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.log(Logger.java:765)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:221)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:749)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.deliverOrBuffer(WsLogger.java:407)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:517 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.log(WsLogger.java:385)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.logp(WsLogger.java:639)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJAR(ScannerContextImpl.java:282)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scanJARs(ScannerContextImpl.java:315)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.WARScannerContext.scanInternal(WARScannerContext.java:76)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.scan(ScannerContextImpl.java:87)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl.getScannedClasses(ScannerContextImpl.java:70)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.scanForHandlesTypesClasses(WebAppImpl.java:764)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:605)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:409)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   ... 100 more
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:607)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:243)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:134)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:585)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)
[8/22/16 14:04:02:518 GMT+02:00] 00000098 SystemErr     R   ... 120 more
```

just include spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server in the pom , deploy to WAS , start the application --> exception generated

if you remove the starter from the pom and deploy the application , application can be started and stopped several times and working normally.

so I can't get why eureka server starter break the logback and give this exception

project attached if anyone interested to give it a try[demo application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zkltexaqhlmjj0m/BootCallBackDemo.rar?dl=0).

note : after deploy the application , stop all the server and start it , application start successfully , stop it and start it solely , it generate the exception again.

i believe it related to classpath loader conflict or something similar but i can't catch it.

any help !

Comment: Any solution you got for this?

We are facing same issue with different stack:
Java 11, Spring Boot 2.6.6, App Dynamics which uses IBM Agent.
Wrapped in Docker and deployed to AWS ECS

We checked for dependent jars and we can find all relevant jars with specific versions in place but unable to figure out exact root cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the example project!

When I build your war I see

```
$ jar tvf bootcallbackdemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war|grep logback
   521 Mon Aug 29 09:07:26 MDT 2016 WEB-INF/classes/logback-spring.xml
304075 Fri Apr 08 08:49:58 MDT 2016 WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar
470782 Fri Apr 08 08:50:02 MDT 2016 WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.7.jar
```

`ThrowableProxy` is in `logback-classic-1.1.7.jar`.

Unfortunately, I don't have websphere, but my guess is that websphere has an old version of logback that doesn't contain `ThrowableProxy` and is using that over the one defined in `WEB-INF/lib`. Is there a setting that can change the precedence (there was in weblogic years ago)?

Comment: Hi Spencer , yess i tried to change class loader to parent last , but still the same issue. also i follow the guess of jar conflict before but i couldn't find logback jars in websphere , i will try it again next week and update you with the result.